# Trigger MySQL updating wrong

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

I have a problem with a trigger in a mysql database,
the problem is, I have this trigger:

```
BEGIN
    IF OLD.sincronizado = 'S' THEN
        SET NEW.sincronizado = 'N';
    END IF;
END
```

every time a record in the table to be updated, I need to "sincronizado" column BE AMENDED TO 'N'. It works when the column is 'S' and is updated it changes to 'N', but when it is already 'S' and I give an update to 'S', it changes to 'N'.

ps: "before update".

Answer (score 0):

You need to add additional condition as

```
IF OLD.sincronizado = 'S' and NEW.sincronizado <> 'S' THEN
```

So it will looks like

```
BEGIN
     IF OLD.sincronizado = 'S' and NEW.sincronizado <> 'S' THEN
        SET NEW.sincronizado = 'N';
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: that resolves the update on the 'sincronizado' field, but when I change another column of the record, the 'sincronizado' does not change to 'N'.

Comment: So you mean for every column change it will change to `N` ? In that case you may need to add condtion for each col since update statement will check each column.

Comment: Abhik Chakraborty not quite understand your question, but What do I want, is that whenever there is any change to the registry, the "sincronizado" column is changed to 'N'.

I will have to put a condition for each column?
the trigger no longer do it alone?

Comment: Yes but the issue is you do not want to change the value of `sincronizado` if its already `S`, so if you update some other column but not `sincronizado` the update command sees the old and the new value as `S` so this condition becomes true.

Comment: actually I want to upgrade, the problem is that when I update it to 'S' and it is already as 'S', it changes to 'N', I can not see why this is happening.

Comment: Yes if you update any column then it finds the `OLD.sincronizado` in the trigger and with your old condition `IF OLD.sincronizado = 'S' THEN` this becomes true. so no matter what column you update if sincronizado is S then it comes inside the condition.

Comment: Add the table structure into the question and the col names that you will update.

Comment: I auditioned in a column and it worked, the problem is that too many columns and several tables that require such trigger .. thanks.

Comment: Well if you have too many columns then I with the logic that you are trying to accomplish I am afraid you need to add all of them in the condition.

Comment: yes, the way I did worked, but I need to put condition for each column, do not want it, want a smarter solution =(. is there a?

Comment: I dont know if there is a smarter one may be I will check if I come up with some optimized solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    BEGIN
    IF ( OLD.sincronizado = 'S' AND NEW.sincronizado != 'S' )THEN
        SET NEW.sincronizado = 'N';
ENDIF ;

END
```

Comment: the entire trigger is that I posted.
just need the 'sincronizado' field is changed to 'N' when update. but when it is 'S' and I give update for 'S' it does not switch to 'N'.

Comment: not work.. not updated to sincronizado= 'N' when I change other fields.